# Adding required attribute when uncollapsed (javascript or JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

we got the code below and we want the input to be required when the collapsed attribute = false.

```
                    <div id="memberThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="input-group col-xs-2">
                                <label>Voornaam:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Voornaam" id="teamlid3Voornaam">
                            </div>
```

Comment: Which collapsed attribute? You meant the class `panel-collapse collapse`?

Comment: I don't see a collapsed attribute, but a class "collapse"?

Comment: Yea, I mean that the inputfield with id 'teamlid3Voornaam' must be required to fill in when it is uncollapsed (open) en not anymore when it's closed again

Comment: So, what is your question? Is it about how to identify when is it collapsed or not? Or is it how to make it required?

Comment: Your question is not clear. And do you have the code you tried...?